# hello gyes comment je peux faire la foction de pdf dans le backend node.js 14 et le frent angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, mongoose

hello gyes comment je peux faire la foction de pdf dans le backend node.js 14 et le frent angular

i try to post pdf in backend node.js 14
app.use('/img/cvPdf', express.static(path.join('Backend/images','Backend/cvPdf')));
const MIME_TYPE = {
'image/png': 'png',
'image/jpeg': 'jpg',
'image/jpg': 'jpg',

}
const MINE_TYPE={
"application/pdf":"pdf"
} is it true ?